# вход на dnevnik.ru сайт с помощью requests

Tags: python

Проблема в том, что когда я беру html код то там нет того, который создаётся через php(БД). Можно ли как-то это исправить. Использую библиотеку requests. Вот код:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('https://login.dnevnik.ru/login', data={'login': 'ЛОГИН', 'password': 'ПАРОЛЬ'})
r = s.get('https://dnevnik.ru/user')
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправлюсь, скорее всего у вас авторизация происходит на разных доменах. Возможно посмотрите под дебагером куки.

---

Первым запросом вы авторизуетесь, а во втором вы не используете вашу авторизацию, поэтому и не видите то что нужно. Используйте сессии http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: код в вопросе уже сессию использует.